# как применить разные анимации на один элемент при нажатии кнопки

Tags: html, jquery, css

я попыталась это сделать, но получается что когда нажимаю, элемент исчезает, потом только при повторном нажатии кнопки появляется и анимируется.

попробуйте сами:

```js
$('button:nth-child(1)').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').addClass('activate bounce').toggle()

})

$('button:nth-child(2)').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').addClass('activate bounce').toggle()

})

$('button:nth-child(3)').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').addClass('activate rubberBand').toggle()

})


//может это из-за togggle()?
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.activate {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.rubberBand {
  animation-name: rubberBand;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>lorem</h1>

<div class="buttons">
  <button>animate1</button>
  <button>animate2</button>
  <button>animate3</button>
  <button>nfdf</button>
  <button>nfjnwkrnw</button>
  <button>rejrnwnr</button>
  <button>jenrw</button>
  <button>ernkw</button>

</div>
```

как это предотвратить?

p.s. красивые анимации взяты [отсюда](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: .toggle - Показывает или скрывает элементы в наборе объекта jQuery. Вам нужно сначала очистить класс, а затем добавить нужный класс с анимацией

Comment: а как очистить класс? можно пример, пожалуйста

Comment: $('h1').removeClass(); - Вызов removeClass без параметров приведет к удалению всех классов элементов.

Comment: сработало, благодарю!:)

Comment: ой, нет, что-то не так..  стиль прописанный для H1 тоже, кажется, удаляется:(( что делать?

Comment: .removeClass() удаляет все классы, как лучше сделать хз, можно просто добавить в `addClass('activate bounce')` перед `activate` ваши классы, которые используются для h1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал на примере [сайта](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Добавляем класс и через `setTimeout` удаляем его через n кол-во времени(Задержка в миллисекундах, 1000 миллисекунд равны 1 секунде.)

```js
$('button:nth-child(1)').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').addClass('activate bounce');
  setTimeout(function(){$('h1').removeClass('activate bounce');},1000);

})

$('button:nth-child(2)').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').addClass('activate bounce');
  setTimeout(function(){$('h1').removeClass('activate bounce');},1000);

})

$('button:nth-child(3)').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').addClass('activate rubberBand');
  setTimeout(function(){$('h1').removeClass('activate rubberBand');},1000);

})


//может это из-за togggle()?
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.activate {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.rubberBand {
  animation-name: rubberBand;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>lorem</h1>

<div class="buttons">
  <button>animate1</button>
  <button>animate2</button>
  <button>animate3</button>
  <button>nfdf</button>
  <button>nfjnwkrnw</button>
  <button>rejrnwnr</button>
  <button>jenrw</button>
  <button>ernkw</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

В место

> $('h1').toggle();

используй

> $('h1').toggleClass();

`.toggle()` предназначен для другого. Добавляет `style="display: none;"`

```js
$('button:nth-child(1)').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').toggleClass('activate bounce');
})
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.activate {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.rubberBand {
  animation-name: rubberBand;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>lorem</h1>

<div class="buttons">
  <button>animate1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: оо спасибо, заработало! а как сделать так чтобы анимировалось при первом нажатии? тут происходит только со второго и еще почему то не работают как следует если добавить еще пару других работающих кнопок